# why the for loop not giving factorial?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am using for-loop to get factorial of a number but the code is not working. Can anyone fix the error using for loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    /*35.   Making a program to give factorial */
    int factorial = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int num;

    printf("Enter the number whose factorial needed");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    for (i = 1; i <= num; i--) {
        factorial *= i;            
        printf("%d\n", factorial);
    }
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: change `for (i=1;i <= num;i--)` to `for (i=1;i <= num;i++)`. and take the printf statement outside the loop. also `#include <conio.h.>` should be `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: Note that you can probably only calculate 12! before you run into overflows.

Comment: thanks it was really helpfull....

Answer (score 3):

Change i-- to i++ in the for loop

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason why this is happening is because you have the following
`for(int i =1;i <num; i--)` when you really want i++;

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is not correct, increment the counter instead of decrement

```
for (i=1;i <= num;i++) {
//-----------------^
```